# Failed on consuming a SSL Https 443 non IIS/.NET Webservice via a C# .NET client.

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, ssl

If you ever thought you can consume a webservice running on a server that only runs HTTPS using .NET...give it up:

Is not possible, the proxy files created by the VS, spread all over the XML config files HTTP URIes, althought you added the reference using HTTPS prefix.

Programatically adding the server's certificate to the client, also fails.

Resulting all cases to "80 port calling to the server", instead of the expected 433 (ssl)

```
X509Certificate2 certConfiableServidor = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\WebSite1\certs\ServerERES_pre.cer");
 Client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate=certConfiableServidor;
```

Client is a proxy class created by the UI using Add webservice reference.
Calling method to the server It always ends up with exception message telling about "Timeout, port 80 unreachable."

If I can only make the proxy properly call the server methods using port 443 instead of unsecure 80...

Comment: So what you're saying is (unless I've misunderstood) - you can't consume a WCF service in your .net code if the service is only available on HTTPS?..

Comment: Yes.that's it. https is being systematically ignored by the proxy created by the VS UI (2008  & 2012). Finally (yesterday) I've findout that you must create the WS proxy class using the comand line code :

Comment: wsdl /language:CS https://ServerURL/myService?WSDL